# What is the best way to make massive clones running at background layers in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning unity and developing my first test 2D game, there's one effect that I'd like to be accomplished but lack of knowledge, so here it is:

my goal:
I want to make a scene that lots of enemy game objects running at background, each of the enemy is running toward the foreground layer, so visually, it becomes bigger and larger while running toward

my thoughts:
I have multiple layers in background and set with different z axis
my main camera is using perspective projection
I make a virtual collider to fulfill the running path between 2d background layers
then clone those enemy game objects conditionally

edit:
I took the comment from @derek that use animation, then apply it to the prefab, and then I use Instantiate() to spawn the objects multiple times. More specifically around 150 times, it works but the fps is ... prophetic
Any ideas that how to optimize the cloning speed?

again, I'm a total newbie so my approach could be improper, and hoping to get better ideas here to help me with my first game, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you mean. Have you thought about using an animation to simply scale them from 0.1 to 1?

Comment: @DerekC.tks for reply, the scene will probably use more than 300-400 cloned objects from the same prefab, and when those objects (I call them enemy) running from background toward the foreground
Since I'm only making 2D game, so enemies will need to run through mountain background layers that set with the different Z axis, something like they are coming uphill, downhill toward to the foreground,  I'm thinking to use an invisible 3D collider, For one animation, I don't know how to acheive, is this more effecient? tks

Comment: Just a headsup: you can not use a 2D and a 3D collider on the same object. there is a workaround to this where you make a container gameobject that has 2 child objects. one with 2D colliders and one with 3D. Then make sure that you manage which one is enabled at what time so that they dont interfere with eachother.

Comment: Why don't you do 2.5D? You can have all in 3D but showing/looking towards one axis only. That applies if uou have 3d assets of course.

Comment: @BartKuijer tks you, good to know this trick

Comment: @DerekC.for now, I end up as what you have suggested, using animation to transform the object from small to large to mimic the depth effect, although I'm not sure cloning such animation for 300 objects randomly at once is a good way to go. Thank you!